# Nested form to route to proper controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The routes define

```
  resources :interruptions do
    collection do
      post :pause
      post :restart
    end
  end
```

However, within an intervento_controller show action, where `@interruption = Interruption.new` is declared, a form to create a related record

```
<%= form_for @interruption, url: pause_interruptions_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :intervento_id, value: @intervento.id %>
  <%= submit_tag "Pausa", name: 'pausa_intervento' %>
<% end %>
```

rails is routing to the intervento action, not the one stated in the form_for url declaration.

```
Started PATCH "/interventos/32" for ::1 at 2017-01-17 13:04:49 +0100 
Processing by InterventosController#update as HTML  
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", [...] "interruption"=>{"intervento_id"=>"32"}, "pausa_intervento"=>"Pausa", "id"=>"32"}
```

The model Intervento does allow `accepts_nested_attributes_for :interruptions`, however I expected this not be necessary as the form declares the action to be routed to.  Also, only one record is being created or edited at a time.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: you might have the same route twice, paste the complete routes file.

Comment: I did check for that. Not the case...

Answer (score 0):

Your `pause` action is defined on collection, i.e `/interventos/post`,
however, your form is defined for an `interruption` instance.

You think you meant to do

```
  resources :interruptions do
    member do
      post :pause
      # post :restart
    end
  end
```

and you also need to change `pause_interruptions_path` accordingly.

Also try use `f.submit`
`submit_tag` seems being treated as a input field.

Comment: Even setting up the routes that way, the error arises as `Processing by InterventosController`, i.e. identical.

Comment: Have you whitelisted `interruptions_attributes` in permitted_params?

Comment: Yes.  But that is not the problem; the console advises you when there are unpermitted params.  As per the error above, the action is launched towards PATCH on Intervento class

Comment: Can you try change `submit_tag` to `f.submit`? It seems the `submit_tag` is being submitted as a input value.

Comment: is `<%= form_for @interruption, url: pause_interruptions_path do |f| %>` nested in another form? I think you need to use `f.fields_for` instead.

Comment: Yes, that irons out one issue. Now it `Processing by InterventosController#update`, then `Unpermitted parameter: interruption`.

Comment: I do not think it is necessary to pursue the matter here - it is a question of nested forms and how they are handled.  For my particular case, it highlighted a lower-level problem in terms of the complexity of the action. Best regards.

Comment: You may want to close the question now as it not relative anymore.